# Installing certificates on arch

Tags: networking, arch-linux, certificates, wpa2

at school the wifi network is wpa2 with peap and mschapv2 requireing a certificate to authenticate and connect along with user name and password

i have obtained a copy of the certificate from the school's it technitians

in ubuntu to add the certificate i copied it into `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra` and then ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` 
which gided me through the screens below
[image: image 1]
[image: Image 2]

and gave the output
[image: image 3]
 however i would now like to move from ubuntu to arch linux but have been un able to add the certificate and connect to the network could anyone please tell me what the equivilent command is in arch.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [`trust`](https://p11-glue.github.io/p11-glue/manual/trust.html) command provided by the [`p11-kit`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/p11-kit/) package:

`sudo trust anchor --store ~/my-ca-cert.crt`

Answer (score 7):

I cannot find anything on the Arch wiki about installing ca certificates. There was a [news update](https://www.archlinux.org/news/ca-certificates-update/) in 2014. The certificate needs to be added to `/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/` and must have a `.crt` extension. Then run `trust extract-compat`. Details of the process can be found with `man 8 update-ca-trust`.

Comment: I have already tried this but it produces no results

Comment: Try to append your cert to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. For me, `cat /etc/squid/ssl_cert/squid.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the answers above in **2022** in Arch Linux I had to:

```
cp my-ca.crt /etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract
```

I then saw my custom `CA` added at the top of `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

On Chrome based browsers I also added my custom `CA` under:

- **Privacy & Security => Manage certificates => Authorities => Import**

I used `xca` to create the `CA` & server certificate with [these helpful notes](https://www.wildtechgarden.ca/deploy-admin/using-xca-to-create-private-ssl-certificates/).

[image]